# Filter duplicate rows of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to filter the rows of a pandas DataFrame based on some conditions and I'm having difficulties with it. The DataFrame is like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'cus_id': [1111, 2222, 2222, 3333, 4444, 4444, 4444, 5555, 5555], 
                  'cus_group' : [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]})

print(df)

   cus_id  cus_group
0    1111          1
1    2222          1
2    2222          0
3    3333          0
4    4444          1
5    4444          1
6    4444          0
7    5555          0
8    5555          0
```

The selection I would like to apply is the following:

For all **cus_id** that appear more than once (i.e. for all duplicates **cus_id**), keep only the ones where **cus_group** is equal to 1. Caution: If a **cus_id** appears more than once but it only belongs to group 0, we keep all instances of this customer.

Visually, the resulting DataFrame I want is like so:

```
   cus_id  cus_group
0    1111          1
1    2222          1
2    3333          0
3    4444          1
4    4444          1
5    5555          0
6    5555          0
```

As you can see for **cus_id** = 5555, even though it does appear twice, we keep both records since it only belongs to group 0. I have tried a few things using the duplicated() method but with no success. Any additional help is would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT:** The solution provided by **jezrael** works perfectly for the example above. I have noticed that in the real DataFrame I'm using there are cases where customers are linked to `NaN` group. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'cus_id': [1111, 2222, 2222, 3333, 4444, 4444, 4444, 5555, 5555, 6666, 7777, 7777, ], 
                  'cus_group' : [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

print(df)

    cus_id  cus_group
0     1111        1.0
1     2222        1.0
2     2222        0.0
3     3333        0.0
4     4444        1.0
5     4444        1.0
6     4444        0.0
7     5555        0.0
8     5555        0.0
9     6666        NaN
10    7777        NaN
11    7777        NaN
```

Using the solution of **jezrael** those customers are dropped. Is there a quick fix to keep **ALL** (duplicates included) such cases in the final DataFrame? Visually (after filtering):

```
    cus_id  cus_group
0     1111        1.0
1     2222        1.0
2     3333        0.0
3     4444        1.0
4     4444        1.0
5     5555        0.0
6     5555        0.0
7     6666        NaN
8     7777        NaN
9     7777        NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is filter all `0` groups with compare `0` and [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) and chain with `|` for bitwise `OR` for `1` rows:

```
df = df[df['cus_group'].eq(0).groupby(df['cus_id']).transform('all') | df['cus_group'].eq(1)]
```

Or if possible only `1` and `0` values in `cus_group` column:

```
df = df[df.groupby('cus_id')['cus_group'].transform('nunique').eq(1) | df['cus_group'].eq(1)]
```

---

```
print(df)
   cus_id  cus_group
0    1111          1
1    2222          1
3    3333          0
4    4444          1
5    4444          1
7    5555          0
8    5555          0
```

Comment: Thank you, @jezrael. This works really nicely. I have noticed that if a customer belong to group `NaN`, then that customer will be dropped when applying the filter. Is there an easy way to adjust your solution to retain those customers? I have added a sub-question to my original post to explain this.

Comment: @glpsx - Can you test `df = df[df['cus_group'].eq(0).groupby(df['cus_id']).transform('all') | df['cus_group'].eq(1) | df['cus_group'].isna()]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Fast solution will be filtered NaN group and then append to the table:

```
df = df[df.groupby('cus_id')['cus_group'].transform('nunique').eq(1)
     | df['cus_group'].eq(1)].append(df[df['cus_group'].isnull()])
   print(df)
```

Answer:

```
    cus_id  cus_group
0     1111        1.0
1     2222        1.0
3     3333        0.0
4     4444        1.0
5     4444        1.0
7     5555        0.0
8     5555        0.0
9     6666        NaN
10    7777        NaN
11    7777        NaN
```